# After for-loop, returned array is wrong

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have something like that:

```
$n = 2;

$items = array();

$result = array(); // new array with random items

$random_items = array_rand( $items, $n );

for( $f=0; $f<=$n; $f++ ) {
  $result[] = $items[$random_items[$f]];
}
```

`$items` is sth like

```
Array ( [0] => file1.jpg [1] => file2.png [2] => file3.jpg ... and so on )
```

This is working OK... but if I set **`$n`** to **`1`** then the script is not working or working incorrectly!

If $n == 2 (or more) the result array have last element's value empty

```
Array ( [0] => 20141125-17826a4b34.png [1] => 20141125-27fe57561d.jpg [2] => )
```

If $n == 1 (exactly) the result array is like

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => )
```

The result array should be the same format as items array but only with $n random items.

Thanks in advance!

**Working**

```
if( $n > 1 ) {
  for( $f=0; $f<$n; $f++ ) {
    $result[] = $items[$random_items[$f]];
  }
}
elseif( $n == 1 ) {
  $result[0] = $items[$random_items];
}
```

Comment: Issue #1: `$f<=$n;` should be `$f<$n;`, though `foreach($random_items as $f)` would be easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `$f < $n` instead of `$f <= $n`

```
for( $f=0; $f < $n; $f++ ) {
  $result[] = $items[$random_items[$f]];
}
```

Because, when you're using `$f <= $n` its running up to `0,1 (when, $n = 1)` OR `0,1,2 (when $n = 2)` and you're missing the last indexed element.

> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random
>   entry(not array).Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned.

So, This means, when you're using `$n = 1`, then `$random_items` is just a value(not array). eg.

for `$n = 1, $random_items = 4;`

but for `$n >= 2, $random_items = [1, 6, 3, 6];`

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky Yes, I added explanation below.. for `$n = 1` `array_rand()` return a value only not array of value.